# How can I modify specific part of a binary scalar in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, binary

I adopt select(), sysread(), syswrite() mechanism to handle socket messages where messages are sysread() into $buffer (binary) before they are syswritten.

Now I want to change two bytes of the message, which denote the length of the whole message. At first, I use following code:

```
my $msglen=substr($buffer,0,2); # Get the first two bytes
my $declen=hex($msglen);
$declen += 3;
substr($buffer,0,2,$declen); # change the length
```

However, it doesn't work in this way. If the final value of $declen is 85, then the modified $buffer will be "0x35 0x35 0x00 0x02...". I insert digital number to $buffer but finally got ASCII!

I also tried this way:

```
my $msglen=substr($buffer,0,2); # Get the first two bytes,binary
$msglen += 0b11; # Or $msglen += 3;
my $msgbody=substr($buffer,2); # Get the rest part of message, binary
$buffer=join("", $msglen, $msgbody);
```

Sadly, this method also failed. The result is such as"0x33 0x 0x00 0x02..." I just wonder why two binary scalar can't be joined into a binary scalar?

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $msglen=substr($buffer,0,2); # Get the first two bytes
my $number = unpack("S",$msglen);
$number += 3;
my $number_bin = pack("S",$number);
substr($buffer,0,2,$number_bin); # change the length
```

Untested, but I think this is what you are trying to do... convert a string with two bytes representing a short int into an actual int object and then back again.

Comment: You are right!
I have been suffering with this problem for many days! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have found another workable way -- using vec

```
vec($buffer, 0, 16) += 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join two binary buffers in Perl directly all you have to do is call [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) to get an ASCII and then join it and call [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) on it to get back.

Comment: There's no problem joining binary strings, but you have to join the right data.